# During migration commit links are "Fixed", "Removed" but not "Added"

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools, vsts-sync-migrator

When I run migration in azure-devops-migration-tools, there is Fixing, Removing of commit links, but no Adding.

[image]

As a result commit links do not get migrated.
However it doesn't reproduce in every project - in most projects this works fine and commits also get added. For example:

[image]

My WorkItemMigrationConfig:

```
 {
      "ObjectType": "VstsSyncMigrator.Engine.Configuration.Processing.WorkItemMigrationConfig",
      "ReplayRevisions": true,
      "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
      "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
      "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
      "UpdateSourceReflectedId": false,
      "BuildFieldTable": false,
      "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
      "QueryBit": "AND [System.ID] = 41128",
      "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
      "Enabled": true,
      "LinkMigration": true,
      "AttachmentMigration": true,
      "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
      "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
      "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": false,
      "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
      "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
      "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
      "AttachmentMazSize": 480000000,
      "CollapseRevisions": false
    }
```

I suspect this may be project specific, but currently I have no idea what is causing the issue. What may be the reason for this?

//edit

After some research in the tool's source code I have found that commit links are only added if commit link URIs are different (https://github.com/nkdAgility/azure-devops-migration-tools/blob/9ef6ee4fd863de30d8a2179450bc86cb5cfafeb5/src/VstsSyncMigrator.Core/Execution/OMatics/RepoOMatic.cs#L137)
In my case these links are the same because TFS / AzureDevops project IDs are the same, as destination project is a result of cloning source project's collection.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work the Git repository must be in the target first! If you have changes the name of the Git Repository you must add it to the mapping.

> FixGitCommitLinks - Allows you to fix the migrated Git commit hooks (and
> thus external links) to point to the new repository in the target
> project. If the source and target repository names are the same, this
> will work out of the box. If the target repository has a different
> name, you can specify that name via the “TargetRepository” property

https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/

This is slightly out of date, you need to use a "GitRepoMapping" similar as the "WorkItemTypeDefinition" element in the yaml that maps all of the old names to the new names. Again it is only needed when you use a different name from the source.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. My git repo is in target project, git repositories names are the same, and on top of that my projects ids are identical, but one project is in TFS, and another is in Azure Devops. I suspect that these ids are identical as we first migrated whole TFS collection (not using azure-devops-migraiton-tools), and now I am only syncing work items.

Comment: That is a scenario that has never been tested. It should only copy over the work items that have been changed, but that would require the ReflectedWorkItemID to have been updated.

Comment: You will need to download the source code and update the ReflectedItemID logic to just load a work item of the same ID. That is VERY dangerous for projects that have both migrated and imported collections .